# Find all Lucene documents with at least the given query term frequencies

Tags: lucene

How do I search a Lucene index to get only those documents where the field "patterns" contains: the word "C" at least 4 times, AND the term "CN" at least 4 times, AND the word "N" at least 2 times?

Here's what I'm doing:

I'm slowly getting to grips with Lucene, but there's still a long way to go. I'm using it for chemistry search idea, where a compound like water (H2O) is translated into the "document" containing the patterns "O H H OH OH" and methanol (CH3OH) is translated into the patterns "C H H H O H CH CH CH CO OH".

(The actual code omits hydrogens, and uses substructures up to size 7. There are several thousand "words" in the average document, which contains many repeats. I'm researching if this approach is useful.)

I've created the index using something like (this is through the pylucene interface):

```
dirname = SimpleFSDirectory(File(indexDir))
analyzer = WhitespaceAnalyzer(Version.LUCENE_30)
writer = IndexWriter(dirname, analyzer, True, IndexWriter.MaxFieldLength.UNLIMITED)

for compound_id, patterns in process_molecules(input_molecules):
    doc = Document()
    doc.add(Field("compound_id", compound_id, Field.Store.YES, Field.Index.ANALYZED))
    f = Field("patterns", patterns, Field.Store.YES, Field.Index.ANALYZED)
    f.setOmitNorms(True)
    doc.add(f)
    writer.addDocument(doc)

writer.optimize()
writer.close()
```

I'm only using WhitespaceAnalyzer since I don't want any stemming. I use OmitNorms() since I don't want any term length normalization. (Should I be doing anything else?)

The similarity search code gives results which look okay, although I'll need some more testing.

I also want to use the index for "substructure searches." That is, if someone sketches a chemical substructure with 6 atoms in a ring (4 carbons and 2 nitrogens), then I want to give them all the structures which contain that ring as a substructure.

In the complex case, this requires a subgraph isomorphism search. I can reject obvious mismatches by converting this into a text search case. The pattern document for that ring is "C C N C C N CN CC CN CN CC CN". All compounds which contain this ring substructure must have a corresponding pattern document with at least 4 "C"s, 2 "N"s, 4 "CN"s, and 2 "CC"s. Therefore, I can replace some of my expensive subgraph isomorphism search code with a filter based on pattern frequencies.

The problem is, I don't know how to specify that frequency-based query.

Answer (score 0):

If you change your structure you can easily search with filters.

Consider a different field for each element that holds the number of atoms in the compound. So H2O is indexed as h:2, O:1, C:0; CH3OH is indexed as C:1, H:4, O:1. 
You can also add another field for compounds like OH.

With this document structure you can use filters and range queries for searching.
For example your first query would be like `C:[4 TO 10000] AND CN:[4 TO 10000] AND N:[2 TO 10000]`

Comment: That's easy enough to do. (I'll have to encode some fields, since I have terms like [Cu] for copper, but that's not hard.) Can I also use those fields for similarity, or do I need to keep the "patterns" field for that?

Comment: What I suggest is make a field for each atom in periodic table. For each field you store the number of the atoms. For the similarity part if having same amount of atoms is enough to be similar discarding the bonding between them then no other field is required; just search with range query. But if bonding is important then add an additional field for   holding the patterns like `patterns: OH CO`.